# Abaqus 2020 Linker error with Intel OneAPI Fortran Compiler

Tags: linker, fortran, intel-fortran, abaqus

Installation steps:

1. Installed Visual Studio Community 2019, ensured Desktop C++
   development is selected.
2. Installed OneAPI Basic and then HPC.
3. Installed Abaqus 2020. Added the path of ifort to system path. This
   enables calling ifort in system cmd.
4. Followed instructions in this
   [blog](https://info.simuleon.com/blog/free-fortran-compiler-on-windows-for-abaqus-material-modeling-0) and added

   @call "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\env\vars.bat" intel64 vs2019

   to abq2020.bat.

Abaqus verify -user_std passes successfully. Suggesting Abaqus is linked correctly with Fortran compiler. However, when attempting to run my own Fortran umat, Abaqus compiles the code but fails at the linking step with the following errors:

```
Begin Linking Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
libifcoremt.lib(for_vm.obj) : error LNK2005: for_allocate already defined in LIBIFCOREMD.LIB(libifcoremd.dll)
libifcoremt.lib(for_vm.obj) : error LNK2005: for_deallocate already defined in LIBIFCOREMD.LIB(libifcoremd.dll)
libifcoremt.lib(for_close.obj) : error LNK2005: for_close already defined in LIBIFCOREMD.LIB(libifcoremd.dll)
libifcoremt.lib(for_open.obj) : error LNK2005: for_open already defined in LIBIFCOREMD.LIB(libifcoremd.dll)
   Creating library standardU.lib and object standardU.exp
standardU_static.lib(SMAStsStdU_IF.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
standardU_static.lib(SMAStsUsubs_IF.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
standardU_static.lib(contactperm.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
standardU_static.lib(creep.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
standardU_static.lib(dflow.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
standardU_static.lib(dflux.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
standardU_static.lib(disp.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
standardU.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
standardU_static.lib(dload.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\zf1005.AD\AppData\Local\Temp\zf1005_test_1172\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
Abaqus Error: Problem during linking - Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines.
```

I believe the issue is with the multitude of library-related linker options, shown below. These library options are the same for many versions of Abaqus installed, such as 2019, 2020, and 2023, so I am not sure what is actually the problem.

```
link_sl=['LINK',
         '/nologo', '/INCREMENTAL:NO', '/subsystem:console', '/machine:AMD64',#'/NOENTRY',
         '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB',
         '/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFCOREMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFPORTMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBMMD.LIB',
         '/DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib',
         '/FIXED:NO', '/dll',
         '/debug', # <-- Debugging
         '/def:%E', '/out:%U', '%F', '%A', '%L', '%B', 
         'oldnames.lib', 'user32.lib', 'ws2_32.lib', 'netapi32.lib', 'advapi32.lib']

link_exe=['LINK',
          '/nologo', '/INCREMENTAL:NO', '/subsystem:console', '/machine:AMD64', '/STACK:20000000',
          '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFCOREMD.LIB',
          '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFPORTMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBMMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib',
          '/DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib',
          '/FIXED:NO', '/LARGEADDRESSAWARE',
           '/debug', # <-- Debugging
          '/out:%J', '%F', '%M', '%L', '%B', '%O',
          'oldnames.lib', 'user32.lib', 'ws2_32.lib', 'netapi32.lib', 'advapi32.lib']
```

Comment: Looks like the linker now links the dll versions of th libraries automatically. Try removing the .lib versions from your commands. E.g., remove `'/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFCOREMD.LIB'` and other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to Abaqus support, we got the following reply and following the instructions it solved the issue:

- It seems the Fortran compiler (oneAPI) successfully linked but they need to check their C++ compiler (Visual Studio) and linker are seen by Abaqus as well. They can verify this in their support.log file.
- If they get errors related to missing libraries/dlls it could potentially be fixed with the Visual Studio 2019 redistributables Latest supported Visual C++ Redistributable downloads | Microsoft Learn (intalling x86 and x64).
- There are also some bugs/issues with oneAPI, they need to add these 2 lines to the `abaqus_v6env`:

  ```
  compile_fortran += ['/names:lowercase',]

  link_sl='LINK /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB /dll /def:%E /out:%U %F %A %L %B'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem. I think your main objective is to debug the Abaqus subroutines.

I could debug UMAT subroutines with the following `win86_64.env` file:

```py
#-*- mode: python -*-

#############################################################################
#                                                                           #
#     Compile and Link commands for ABAQUS on the Windows 64 Platform       #
#                                                                           #
#############################################################################

#import os # <-- Debugging
#os.environ['GLOBAL_ENABLE_FPE'] = 'TRUE' # <-- Debugging

# Location of the /include directory in the ABAQUS installation
abaHomeInc = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.environ.get('ABA_HOME', ''), os.pardir)) 

compile_cpp=['cl', '/c', '/W0', '/MD', '/TP',
             '/EHsc', '/DNDEBUG', '/DWIN32', '/DTP_IP', '/D_CONSOLE',
             '/DNTI', '/DFLT_LIC', '/DOL_DOC', '/D__LIB__', '/DHKS_NT',
             '/D_WINDOWS_SOURCE', '/DFAR=', '/D_WINDOWS', '/DABQ_WIN86_64', '%P',
             # '/O1', # <-- Optimization
             '/Zi', # <-- Debug symbols
             '/I%I', '/I'+abaHomeInc]

compile_fmu=['win64CmpWrp', '-m64', '-msvc9', 'cl', '/LD', 
             '/D_WINDOWS', '/TC', '/W0',  '/I%I', '/I'+abaHomeInc]

## Fortran compile command for User Subroutines

compile_fortran=['ifort',
                 '/c', '/fpp', '/extend-source', 
                 '/DABQ_WIN86_64',  '/DABQ_FORTRAN',
                 '/iface:cref', '/recursive',
                 '/Qauto',  # <-- important for thread-safety of parallel user subroutines
                 '/align:array64byte',
                 '/Qpc64',                    # set FPU precision to 53 bit significand
                 '/Qprec-div', '/Qprec-sqrt', # improve precision of FP divides and sqrt
                 '/Qfma-',                    # disable floating point fused multiply-add
                 '/fp:precise',               # floating point model: precise 
                 '/Qimf-arch-consistency:true', # math library consistent results
                 '/Qfp-speculation:safe',     # floating point speculations only when safe
                 '/Qprotect-parens',          # honor parenthesis during expression evaluation
                 '/Qfp-stack-check',          # enable stack overflow protection checks
                 '/reentrancy:threaded',      # important for thread-safety
                 #'/Qinit=zero','/Qinit=arrays',  # automatically initialize all arrays to zero
                 #'/Qinit=snan', '/Qinit=arrays', # automatically initialize all arrays to SNAN
                 '/QxSSE3', '/QaxAVX',        # generate SSE3, SSE2, and SSE instructions
                 '/Od', '/Ob0',  # <-- Disable Optimization for Debugging
                 '/Zi',          # <-- Debugging Information
                 '/include:%I', '/include:'+abaHomeInc, '%P']

link_sl=['LINK',
         '/nologo', '/NOENTRY', '/INCREMENTAL:NO', '/subsystem:console', '/machine:AMD64',
         '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB',
         '/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFCOREMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFPORTMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBMMD.LIB',
         '/DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib',
         '/FIXED:NO', '/dll',
         '/debug', # <-- Debugging
         '/def:%E', '/out:%U', '%F', '%A', '%L', '%B', 
         'oldnames.lib', 'user32.lib', 'ws2_32.lib', 'netapi32.lib',
         'advapi32.lib', 'msvcrt.lib', 'vcruntime.lib', 'ucrt.lib']

link_exe=['LINK',
          '/nologo', '/INCREMENTAL:NO', '/subsystem:console', '/machine:AMD64', '/STACK:20000000',
          '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFCOREMD.LIB',
          '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFPORTMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBMMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib',
          '/DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib',
          '/FIXED:NO', '/LARGEADDRESSAWARE',
          '/debug', # <-- Debugging
          '/out:%J', '%F', '%M', '%L', '%B', '%O',
          'oldnames.lib', 'user32.lib', 'ws2_32.lib', 'netapi32.lib',
          'advapi32.lib', 'msvcrt.lib', 'vcruntime.lib', 'ucrt.lib']

## Link command to be used for ABAQUS/MAKE on machines without the Fortran compiler.
## Uncomment it to enable.
#
#link_exe=['LINK', '/nologo', '/INCREMENTAL:NO', '/subsystem:console', '/machine:AMD64', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB',
#          '/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib',
#          '/FIXED:NO', '/LARGEADDRESSAWARE', '/out:%J', '%F', '%M', '%L', '%B', '%O',
#         'oldnames.lib', 'user32.lib', 'ws2_32.lib', 'netapi32.lib',
#         'advapi32.lib', 'msvcrt.lib', 'vcruntime.lib', 'ucrt.lib']

# Remove the temporary names from the namespace
del abaHomeInc
```

In my computer, this file is located in `C:\SIMULIA\EstProducts\2021\win_b64\SMA\site\win86_64.env`. Depending on your Abaqus version and configurations, this path can vary.

Unfortunately, the warning messages remain.

Comment: Does the suggestion in my comment below the question change anything?

Comment: I saw your comment, but I couldn't understand precisely which libraries you suggested removing. Are you suggesting removing all commands with the suffix ".lib"? If yes, are you suggesting removing from the list "link_sl" and "link_exe"?

Comment: Not all of them, Just `LIBIFCOREMD.LIB`. Removing it from the list of libraries for the linker. Either `link_sl` or `link_exe` depending on which one is actually used.

Comment: Removing `LIBIFCOREMD.LIB` from `link_sl` and `link_exe` does not remove the warning messages, but causes an Abaqus Error:
"Abaqus Error: Problem during linking - Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines.
  This error may be due to a mismatch in the Abaqus user subroutine arguments.
  These arguments sometimes change from release to release, so user subroutines
  used with a previous release of Abaqus may need to be adjusted."
I don't think it is a solution. :/